# Looking for a one step solution to appending my SSH public key to a server's authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh, public-key

To get my public key onto a server I normal copy the contents of my public key, then `SSH` into the server, then I run `vi .ssh/authorized_keys`, then paste my key into the file and save.

There has got to be an easier, one step way using SCP or something like that. Of course I want to append my key to `authorized_keys`, not overwrite it and the permissions of `authorized_keys` needs to remain at `600`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also try this one liner:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remote-system 'umask 077; cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: This is perfect. Unfortunately the `ssh-copy-id` is not included in Mac OS X, so this one liner script will have to do and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell  - try `brew install ssh-copy-id`

Comment: This may not work if .ssh directory doesn't exist, its permissions are incorrect, or if .ssh/authorize_keys permissions are incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking into the `ssh-copy-id` tool, for example:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa remoteuser@remote.host
```

More on:

- `ssh-copy-id` man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id
- OpenSSH Speed Tips and Tricks: http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tips/6592/1/

Answer (score 2):

ssh-copy-id is a script that will do exactly what you want:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

Comment: I feel like an idiot, not knowing this command was available on linux machines, but it's not available by default on a Mac. Thanks for the answer thought.

Answer (score 0):

you could also get copymyid from [here](http://www.r1ch4rd.net/). Its a command line application designed to be a replacement for ssh-copy-id on osx. The app appends the specified pub file to your server.