# I have the private DSA key in PEM format. What do I do next to access SSH without a password?

Tags: ssh, ssl, keys, dsa

I have the private DSA key in PEM format. What do I do next to access SSH without a password?

Sample certificate in PEM format:
http://ospkibook.sourceforge.net/docs/OSPKI-2.4.7/OSPKI-html/sample-priv-key.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ah -- I think you are confusing ssh certificates and ssl certificates.

ssh uses two forms of two main forms of two-factor authentication keys: 1) standard RSA or DSA key pairs (public, private) or 2) ssh certificates which (according to `man ssh-keygen`)

> ...consist of a public key, some identity informa-
>        tion, zero or more principal (user or host) names and an optional set of constraints
>        that are signed by a Certification Authority (CA) key.

it goes on to say:

> Note that OpenSSH certificates are a different, and much simpler,
>        format to the X.509 certificates used in ssl(8).

To generate a **normal ssh keypair**, do something like the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f test
```

It is advisable to protect the private key with a password.

Then, by placing the public key (`test.pub` in this case) in the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the target host user's login home, you should be able to login to the target host without a password if sshd is configured to allow this.

```
ssh -i test user@host
```

To generate an **ssh certificate**, do something like the following:

1. `ssh-keygen -f ca_key` # generate a ssh keypair for use as a certificate
2. generate a host key 
   `ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I cert_identifier -h host_key.pub`
3. specify the host key in the server's sshd config file:
   `TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/ssh_cert/host_key.pub`
4. generate a local certificate to access the host using an ssh certificate:
   `ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I cert_identifier user_key.pub`. This should generate user_key-cert.pub

Assuming this has all proceeded properly, `ssh -i user_key user@host` will use the user_key-cert.pub file and login will proceed automatically (if allowed on the server). The server will log a connection from *cert_identifier* if so configured.

ssh certificates are a new feature and still need some usability aspects shaken out. The benefits of them include a central signing key, an alternative to constraining connections through authorized_keys and the possibility of limiting the validity timeperiods of ssh certificates.

Comment: Actually, there is a patch to give ssh X.509 certificate support. See http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/

Answer (score 0):

This may help you - [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/170992/looking-for-a-one-step-solution-to-appending-my-ssh-public-key-to-a-servers-auth)

Or you can use `ssh-copy-id user@host` as well.