# Is it possible to append to a file, by piping between servers/scp/etc.?

Tags: files, remote, scp

**Short version**

How can I pipe text from a local machine/server and append it (not overwrite) to a file in a remote machine/server?

---

**Long version**

I wished to append my `~/.ssh/rsa_pub` (public key) from local to a remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

So I tried this (and hoped for the best):

`scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@local:user@remote/.ssh/authorized_keys`

So I accidently overwrote the remote `authorized_keys` instead of appending to it... Since my accident, I need to append all those authorized_keys that I lost, one by one, using copy-paste.

Is there a way I can append to the remote's authorized_keys, rather than overwriting it?

Perhaps there is a tool made specifically for things like `authorized_keys`, but I am also (and more) interested in a general solution along the lines of:

```
cat local_machine_file.txt >> remote_machine_file.txt
```

Where I only care about appending to the end of the file, and not at a specific line of a file.

---

**What I tried**

Well I read the whole of `man scp`, several ssh key generating tutorials, and [this](https://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux). The latter is actually what inspired me to unintendedly overwrite remote's `authorized_keys`... After reading all these ssh key generating tutorials I am generally frustrating at how much they all seem to focus on "generating private/public keys from scratch", assuming the remote and local machines do not already have `.ssh/*` stuff already in them. I also spent several hours in total searching among: SO, SuperUser and here.

Comment: The `ssh-copy-id` utility solves this problem.

Comment: That's covered as well.

Comment: For all who want to learn either: (i) how to append local ssh public key to remote /.ssh/authorized_keys, and/or (ii) how to append local data to remote file, go here: http://serverfault.com/questions/170992/looking-for-a-one-step-solution-to-appending-my-ssh-public-key-to-a-servers-aut 

@MichaelHampton, thanks mate, I learnt a lot.